# Help analyzing the time-complexity of my algorithm

Tags: functions, asymptotics

So, (this is homework), we are given an array A, and we are asked to create a function where we return True/False if the array contains three elements which sum to a given value.

To formalize:

Given: A and some value, `val`

sum = A[i] + A[j] + A[k]

Note that: 1 < i < j < k

```
equals = False
for i=1 to n
    for j=i to n
        for k=j to n
            sum=A[i]+A[j]+A[k]
            if sum=val
                equals = True
```

The time complexity is obviously O(n^3) but I am having trouble making the formula. This is what I have so far:

```
T(n) = 1+n+n(n-i)+n(n-j)(n-i)+n(n-k)(n-i)(n-j)+????
```

Any help with analyzing the time complexity would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "formula", but if you are counting the number of operations it the algorithm takes, you can't have the indices be in the formula, right? It should depend only on $n$.

Comment: Sorry, about that. I was just a bit annoyed while writing the question and forgot to put some details. I meant the time operations formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just count the number of times the `sum=A[i]+A[j]+A[k]` statement gets executed:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=1}^j 1
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i j \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n i\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1) + 3n(n+1)}{6}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{n(n + 1)((2n + 1) + 3)}{6}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{2n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6}\right] \\
&= \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6} \\
\end{align*}

Alternatively, you could notice that the number of tuples $(i,j,k)$ satisfying $1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq n$ is:
$$
\binom{n}{3} + 2\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}
= \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2)}{6} + 2 \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n
= \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6}
$$

Comment: Wow, thanks! After looking this over, it is a lot more clear to me. But one issue I had was with the `if statement`. It is a condition and depends on the input itself; how could we measure how many times its inside gets executed?

Comment: Typically, we assume the worst-case scenario: every possible tuple makes the condition true, so that its body is always executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a short-cut to get the bound, just count the number of times $i$ is between $1$ and $n/3$, and $j$ is between $n/3 + 1$ and $2n/3$, and $k$ is between $2n/3 + 1$ and $n$. That will give you a lower bound of approximately $n^3/9$ times the inner-most for loop body executes, and your algorithm is obviously $O(n^3)$ because each for loop executes at most $n$ times at its level, so $O(n^3)$ is a tight bound. Note, you can do better than $O(n^3)$ time for this problem, you can get it down to $O(n^2)$ either by sorting the array first, or if you use hashing.